# Getting auto margin to work for center aligning div

Tags: css

I've overlooked something obvious and simple for sure here but I'm going to have to admit defeat and ask on SO for now.

I've made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/b2Anf/).

A simple one. Simply trying to center align the div class `ratings` inside it's parent container. I haven't managed to get any auto margins to work at all after numerous faffing with it.

The code below:-

## CSS

```
.caption {
    padding: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.ratings {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 3px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

## Markup

```
<div class="caption">
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">Product Title</a></h2>

    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating-bar">
        <div class="rating-box"></div>
        <div class="rating" style="width:100%"></div>
        <div class="rating-fill"></div>
    </div>
        <span class="amount"><a href="#">(2)</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.ratings` is a child of `.caption` which has a width of 100%. You want it centered WRT the 100% width container?

Comment: Not working even when `.caption` doesn't have a width defined but I'm after `.ratings` to be center aligned within `.caption` yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ratings` is just a container so you can remove the float from `.rating-bar` and use `display: inline-block` instead, then set `text-align:center` on `.ratings`

```
.ratings {
    text-align: center;
}

.ratings .rating-bar{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float:left; remove this*/
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/b2Anf/1/)**

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. It was specifically the float inside the child element that was not allowing `.ratings` to center align. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a specific width e.g. `150px` on the Ratings class instead of `100%`
Otherwise, 100% width means the calculation of margins = 0 (none left for margins)

Comment: Thanks. Okay, that worked for my Jsfiddle but not on the live site... How best to handle that responsively then if % can't be used?

Answer (score 0):

It's got a width of `100%`, which means the `auto` value computes to 0 pixels. You will need to either:

1) [Specify the width you actually want](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/NEaVR/).

2) [Make it shrink-to-fit with `display: inline-block`, then wrap it in a block with `text-align: center`](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/WzVrC/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, a block level element has a width of 100%, so defining a width of 100% is irrelevant in this case.

Basically, your child element needs to have a defined smaller width than it's parent, in order to be able to center horizontally.

e.g;

```
.ratings {
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```